# Cannot Find Symbol Error with event handler

Tags: java, if-statement, scope, initialization, parseint

I am having trouble trying to initialize a variable correctly. Earlier I was getting a Number Format Exception because I was parsing an integer inside of an empty text field. Now I have created an if statement that checks first to see if the field is empty, then parses an integer inside of it. The problem i'm having now is that my event handler can't recognize the variable, because it is inside the if statement. I tried declaring it outside of the if statement but that didn't work either. Any tips to point me in the right direction? Here is my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class Main extends Application {

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

      ArrayList<Integer> deck;
      deck = new ArrayList<>();
      int i = 1;
      while(i < 52){
         deck.add(i);
         i++;
      }
      final AtomicReference<String> result = new AtomicReference<>("go.");

      Collections.shuffle(deck);

      BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

      HBox top = new HBox(10);
      Label display = new Label(result.toString());
      Button btShuffle = new Button("Shuffle");
      btShuffle.setOnAction(
            e -> {
               Collections.shuffle(deck);
            });
      top.getChildren().add(display);
      top.getChildren().add(btShuffle);

      HBox center = new HBox(10);
      Card card1 = new Card(deck.get(0));
      center.getChildren().add(card1);

      Card card2 = new Card(deck.get(1));
      center.getChildren().add(card2);

      Card card3 = new Card(deck.get(2));
      center.getChildren().add(card3);

      Card card4 = new Card(deck.get(3));
      center.getChildren().add(card4);

      HBox bottom = new HBox(10);
      Label expression = new Label("Please Enter the expression: ");

      TextField tfExpress = new TextField();
      LinkedList<Object> expInput = new LinkedList<>();
      ArrayList<Character> signs = new ArrayList<>();
      signs.add('/');
      signs.add('+');
      signs.add('(');
      signs.add(')');
      signs.add('-');
      signs.add('^');
      signs.add('*');
      signs.add('%');
      String str = tfExpress.getText();
      char tempStor[] = str.toCharArray();
      for(char c: tempStor){
         expInput.add(c);
      }

      if(tfExpress.getText() != null && tfExpress.getText().equals(""))
      {
         int express = Integer.parseInt(str);
      }

      expInput.removeIf(p-> p.equals(signs));

      Button btVerify = new Button("Verify");
      btVerify.setOnAction(
            (ActionEvent e) -> {
               if(card1.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(0)
               && card2.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(1)
               && card3.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(2)
               && card4.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(3)){
                  if(express == 24){
                     result.set("Correct");
                  }
                  else
                     result.set("Incorrect");

               }
               else
                  result.set("The numbers in the expression don't "
                     + "match the numbers in the set.");
            });

      pane.setTop(top);
      pane.setCenter(center);
      pane.setBottom(bottom);

      Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
      primaryStage.setTitle("24 card game");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
   }

   public class Card extends Pane {
      public int cardVal;
      Card(int card){
         Image cardImage;
         cardImage = new Image("card/"+ card +".png");
         cardVal = card;
      }

      public int CardValue(){
         int card = 0;

         if(cardVal <= 13){
            card = cardVal;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 13 && cardVal <= 26){
            card = cardVal - 13;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 26 && cardVal <= 39){
            card = cardVal - 26;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 39 && cardVal <= 52){
            card = cardVal - 39;
         }         
         return card;
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `str` being empty is an acceptable behavior for your code, you need to define a default value for `express` if that is the case. If the default value were `-1`, for example, you would do:

```
int express = (str != null && !"".equals(str)) ? Integer.parseInt(str) : -1;
```

And then later, you should treat the `-1` case accordingly.

You need to initialize `express` like this, so it is effectively final and can be used in the lambda expression.

Comment: Same problem as I posted below with this. "error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final".

Comment: Thank you very much! So why do think this notation works in my code better? I am very intrigued.

Comment: @JohnDoe Since you already did `String str = tfExpress.getText()` you can test `str` directly. I think it looks cleaner, since it is shorter. Also I think you meant the `if` condition to be `true` when the text is different from `""`, but you had it inversed in your logic.

Comment: @JohnDoe Glad to help. If it works, please consider marking one of the correct answers as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if(tfExpress.getText() != null && tfExpress.getText().equals(""))
{
     int express = Integer.parseInt(str);
}
```

try

```
final int express = (tfExpress.getText() != null && !tfExpress.getText().equals("")) : Integer.parseInt(str) : 0;
```

Comment: hey this is what I tried before. It's telling me "error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final"